# Filtering Object values in C#

Tags: c#, api, linq-to-objects

i've got a C# web Api receiving the following object :

```
     "cars": {
       "bmw": true,
       "benz": false,
       "kia": true,
       "hyundai": false,
       "madza": false,
       "ford": false
   }
```

the class property is as follows :

```
 public CarsViewModel cars{ get; set; }
```

How can i get all the values that are true in the above object?

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: tried to convering the following object to list but didnt work like this : `var cars =  ((IEnumerable)cars).Cast<object>().ToList()`

Comment: Your JSON isn't returning any form of IEnumerable (array / list / etc). It is returning a single object with a bunch of bool properties.

Comment: How are you parsing your json?

Comment: correct, i didnt want to go the long way of check each value if its true, i thought the is a better short way to handle it, maybe in the future i decide to add an extra car name.

Comment: " maybe in the future i decide to add an extra car name.", If you have any power on this json please send a list of true so you don't have to handle the false. and if all possible choice are needed, send a list of True and a list of All. this will be easier for every one.

Comment: the Json data is converted on the model state.

Comment: Show us your CarsViewModel class.

Comment: the class is as follows : `public class CarsViewModel    
{
        public bool bmw { get; set; }
        public bool benz { get; set; }
        public bool kia { get; set; }
        public bool hyundai { get; set; }
        public bool mazda { get; set; }
        public bool ford { get; set; }

    }`

Comment: And what's your desired output? Just strings: `bmw`, `kia`?

Comment: yes, just a string or list  of all values that are true

Comment: Your best option is to convert your car model like the following and then easily filter it : 
public List<Dictionary<string,bool>>  cars {get;set;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the received object into the dictionary and select the key only if value is true.

```
string json = "{\"bmw\": true,\"benz\": false,\"kia\": true,\"hyundai\": false,\"madza\": false,\"ford\": false}";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,bool>>(json);

List<string> cars = dict.Where(x=>x.Value).Select(y=>y.Key).ToList();
```

You can check the result by:

```
cars.ForEach(y => Console.Write("{0}\n", y));
```

PS. For serializing you have to use `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace.

Comment: He, you were faster ... [gist-link example](https://gist.github.com/nkreter/f743e46b9a130d3401938d386fd7cdb1)

Comment: Thanks, had to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars)` then `DeserializeObject`. works perfect but dont know if `SerializeObject` and `DeserializeObject`  the same object is good code practices but thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you try this code

```
 string jsonstring = "{\"cars\": {\"bmw\": \"true\", \"benz\": \"false\",  \"kia\": \"true\",  \"hyundai\": \"false\", \"madza\": \"false\",  \"ford\": \"false\"}}";
 dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonstring); 
 CarsViewModel obj = new CarsViewModel(); 
 var mydetails2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.cars);
 var mydetails3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, bool>>(mydetails2);

  foreach (var pair in mydetails3)
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        if (pair.Value == true)
        {
            if (pair.Key == "bmw")
            {
                obj.bmw = pair.Value;
            }
            else if (pair.Key == "benz")
            {
                obj.benz = pair.Value;
            }
            else if (pair.Key == "kia")
            {
                obj.kia = pair.Value;
            }
            else if (pair.Key == "hyundai")
            {
                obj.hyundai = pair.Value;
            }
            else if (pair.Key == "madza")
            {
                obj.madza = pair.Value;
            }
            else if (pair.Key == "ford")
            {
                obj.ford = pair.Value;
            }

        }
    }
```

I hope its helpful to you..